# Monitoring threads in a machine

Tags: c, linux, process, taskmanager

Is there any way to get information about active threads from other processes in C/C++?

I would like to know total CPU time, input operations, etc. for each thread without changing the source of the target programs and without changing the OS' kernel

Comment: You can write a program that uses `ptrace` (see `man 2 ptrace`). This syscall is what `gdb` uses. It is also what `strace` uses (which may be able to help you without writing code of your own). Also, look at `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>`. These are directories that have [plenty of] information about the various threads

Comment: But is it possible to monitor individual threads with it? And for programs that are already running (meaning you don't run anything on top)?

Comment: Yes. Get the `pid` via (e.g.) `ps ax | grep my_program`. Then, use the `/proc` files to monitor. When using `ptrace` in a program, you can use the `PTRACE_ATTACH` and/or `PTRACE_INTERRUPT` options to attach to running programs. To help understand `ptrace`, download the source to the `strace` program. It helps if the target program is compiled with `-g` and the debug information is _not_ stripped, but this is not required.